# Sublime Text - Como ignorar os aquivos buscados pelo atalho (Goto Anything) CTRL+P?

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

No sublime text temos uma opção chamada `Goto > Goto Anything`, que é acessada através do atalho `CTRL + P`.

Isso é muito útil, pois podemos abrir um arquivo de um projeto simplesmente pressionando `CTRL+P` e digitando o nome (ou parte do nome) do arquivo desejado. Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, as vezes, também aparece na lista de "sugestões" de aquivos para abrir alguns arquivos que fazem parte do **cache** ou mesmo os **minificados**, que não são desejáveis aparecer ali nessa opção.

Como faço para excluir alguns arquivos, por extensão ou por pasta, dessa  busca do `Goto Anything`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai precisar adicionar o seguinte para suas configurações de usuário (Preferências -> Configurações - Usuário) com quaisquer outros diretórios ou tipos de arquivos que você deseja ignorar.

Exemplo:

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS"],
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db"],
"binary_file_patterns": ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
```

fonte: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/exclude-directory-from-go-to-anything/5767/3

Há ainda uma maneira alternativa, onde, criando o projeto através do Sublime Text, você adiciona essas configurações acima no seu arquivo de projeto `projeto.sublime-project`.

Por exemplo:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": ".",
            "folder_exclude_patterns" : [
                "app/storage"
            ],
            "file_exclude_patterns" : [
                "*.jpg", 
                "*.png",
                ".gif",
                "*.min.css",
                "*.min.js",
                "composer.lock"
            ]
        }
    ],

    "settings" : {
        "tab_size" : 4,
        "translate_tabs_to_spaces" : true
    }
}
```

Esse arquivo serve para você poder definir as configurações padrões do seu projeto.